# Addition of two binary numbers

Tags: java, binary, addition

I tried to compere each number by putting the numbers in char arrays and compere them each by each with if conditions. Each outcome should be covered and each outcome should be saved in String `result` but the result of the whole operation is always blank. Java debugger isn't working and I don´t see why it isn't working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryAdder {
    public static String add(String binary1, String binary2) {

        String result = "";
        char[] safea = binary1.toCharArray();
        char[] safeb = binary2.toCharArray();

        int lb1 = binary1.length() - 1;
        int lb2 = binary2.length() - 1;
        char reminder = 0;

        while (lb1 != 0 || lb2 != 0) {
            if (safea[lb1] == 0 && safeb[lb2] == 0 && reminder == 0) {
                result += "0";
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 1 && safeb[lb2] == 0 && reminder == 0) {
                result += "1";
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 1 && safeb[lb2] == 1 && reminder == 0) {
                result += "0";
                reminder = 1;
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 1 && safeb[lb2] == 1 && reminder == 1) {
                result += "1";
                reminder = 1;
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 1 && safeb[lb2] == 0 && reminder == 1) {
                result += "0";
                reminder = 1;
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 0 && safeb[lb2] == 1 && reminder == 1) {
                result += "0";
                reminder = 1;
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 0 && safeb[lb2] == 1 && reminder == 0) {
                result += "1";
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            } else if (safea[lb1] == 0 && safeb[lb2] == 0 && reminder == 1) {
                result += "1";
                lb1--;
                lb2--;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Summand:  ");
        String input1 = scan.next("(0|1)*");
        System.out.print("Summand:  ");
        String input2 = scan.next("(0|1)*");
        scan.close();
        System.out.println("Result: " + add(input1, input2));
    }

}
```

Comment: "safea[lb1]==0" is wrong. you want instead "safea[lb1]=='0' " that is compare the char that represent '0' and not the char with the ordinal 0. (for all other comparisons the same of course) There are more problems(e.g. result reversed) - but thats the one that cause the all empty result.

Comment: Why isn't your debugger working? This looks unnecessarily complex to debug "by hand"

Comment: You are using character array but while comparing you are using integer values. Use character values '1', '0'. There are few more problems one string is smaller or bigger you are not dealing with that and reverse the result as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the bits into integer with [`Integer.parseInt(s, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,int)). You need to use radix of 2:

```
public static String add(String binary1, String binary2) {
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(binary1, 2);
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(binary2, 2);
    return Integer.toBinaryString(i1 + i2);
}
```